# Azure App Service with docker uploading files more than 30 mb

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core

I use Azure App Service with docker. When i trying to upload file with size more than 30 mb i get 500 http status. After logs investigation, i found error:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Request body too large. But when i run this docker image localy all ok. What could be the problem?

Comment: A little more context would help. Upload how?

Comment: Uploading using form data and web api controller

Comment: That's a really vague explanation. Can you show code or commands you're running?

Comment: Code is very simple and typical, web api controller with action method wich takes object with IFormFile property

Comment: How did you deploy docker image to Azure App Service?

Answer (score 0):

For this error, you could try configure `Limits.MaxRequestBodySize` like

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel(opt => {
            opt.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
        });
```

Comment: @VadimBondaruk How did you deploy to Azure app service? Share us detail steps which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: configuration is the same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56482376/increasing-the-maximum-upload-size-limit-for-a-dockerized-asp-net-core-site-runn

Comment: @VadimBondaruk How to reproduce your issue with the link? It works correctly at my side by above code and azure  app service.